# Elasticsearch geo distance sorting not exactly / wrong order

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, geolocation

I am using elasticsearch to get a faster geo distance search functionality for a web project with thousands of locations. The results should be sorted by distance. My search query works, but the order of the results is not correct. The results should be sorted ascending by distance, but there is a result at first with a distance of "9 km", then "100 km" and then "90 km".

My search query JSON is the following (created with php):

```
{
    "index": "profiles",
    "type": "profile",
    "size": 30,
    "from": 0,
    "body": {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "100km",
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 49.449919468911,
                        "lon": 11.073560787681
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "distance": {
            "lang": "groovy",
            "params": {
                "lat": 49.449919468911,
                "lon": 11.073560787681
            },
            "script": "doc['location'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "upgrade_sort": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "has_siegel": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "_geo_distance": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 49.449919468911,
                    "lon": 11.073560787681
                },
                "order": "asc",
                "unit": "km"
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    "fields": [
    "_source",
    "distance"
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I can find no fault, so I hope that someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `_geo_distance` sort in the first position instead of the third one. As it stands, the `_geo_distance` sort will only sort the docs in ascending distance order for those documents that have the same value for `upgrade_sort` and `has_siegel`. Try this instead:

```
{
  "size": 30,
  "from": 0,
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "100km",
            "location": {
              "lat": 49.449919468911,
              "lon": 11.073560787681
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "script_fields": {
      "distance": {
        "lang": "groovy",
        "params": {
          "lat": 49.449919468911,
          "lon": 11.073560787681
        },
        "script": "doc['location'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      {
        "_geo_distance": {
          "location": {
            "lat": 49.449919468911,
            "lon": 11.073560787681
          },
          "order": "asc",
          "unit": "km"
        }
      },
      {
        "upgrade_sort": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      },
      {
        "has_siegel": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": [
    "_source",
    "distance"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, if `_geo_distance` is the first sort criterium, but it should be the third. But the distance sort isn't correctly. For example, I got results like this with my code:

upgrade_sort = 1
has_siegel = 0
distance = 4 km ;

upgrade_sort = 1
has_siegel = 0
distance = 120 km ;

upgrade_sort = 1
has_siegel = 0
distance = 90 km ;

I want to sort by upgrade_sort at first, by has_siegel at second and distance at third.

Comment: It's pretty weird that you get a document at 120km distance since your query specifies that the max distance should be 100km. Can you update your question with the mapping of your `location` field?

Comment: "120km" was an example to demonstrate how the result order is wrong. The search distance is variable in a range between 5km and 500km