# Reuse/cache script fields to use other parts of the query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am working on a project where we need to show distance the listings are from a user location. To show the distance, when lat/lon is given in the input, we calculate distance using a script field called "distance"

```
"script_fields" : {
        "distance" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "Math.round((doc['location'].planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat, params.lon, 0) * 0.001) * 100.0) / 100.0",
                "params" : {
                    "lat"  : -33.8152,
                    "lon" : 151.0012
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, for relevancy search, we want to rank the nearest listing higher and we are calculating the distance again inside the function score query. This is inefficient. I have searched the internet to find a solution but no luck.

**Is there any way to reuse a script field in the other parts of the query or filter or sorting?**

Full Query:

```
GET /listings/_doc/_search
{
    "_source" : true,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "query": { "match": {
          "source_id": 1
        } },
            "functions": [
              {
                "script_score": {
                  "script": {
                    "params": {
                      "dealer": {"a": 5, "b": 6},
                      "photo": {"a": 4, "b": 5},
                      "location": {"lat": -33.8152, "lon": 151.0012}
                    },
                    "source": "(doc['location'].planeDistanceWithDefault(params.location.lat, params.location.lon, 1000) * 0.001 < 25 ? 200000 : 0) + (doc['is_dealer'].value == 1 ? Math.pow(params.dealer.a, params.dealer.b) : 0) + (doc['hasPhoto'].value == 1 ? Math.pow(params.photo.a, params.photo.b) : 0)"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
        }
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "distance" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "Math.round((doc['location'].planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat, params.lon, 0) * 0.001) * 100.0) / 100.0",
                "params" : {
                    "lat"  : -33.8152,
                    "lon" : 151.0012
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating distance using Script Field. It is not possible to use Script Fields to sort the result, because Script Fields are computed after the documents are sorted, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681210/how-to-compute-scores-from-script-fields-in-elasticsearch).

What you can do is to use [Geo Distance Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-request-sort.html#geo-sorting), to sort your result:

```
GET /listings/_doc/_search
{
    "_source" : true,
    "query": {
        /* your query */ 
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "distance" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "Math.round((doc['location'].planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat, params.lon, 0) * 0.001) * 100.0) / 100.0",
                "params" : {
                    "lat"  : -33.8152,
                    "lon" : 151.0012
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_geo_distance" : {
                "location" : {
                    "lat" : -33.8152,
                    "lon" : 151.0012
                },
                "order" : "asc",
                "unit" : "km",
                "mode" : "min",
                "distance_type" : "sloppy_arc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985792/elasticsearch-geo-distance-sorting-not-exactly-wrong-order), it might help.

Comment: We need to use the function score query for custom scoring which is the default scoring for the app. We only use the distance sorting when users want to see nearest listings first.